# UITalbeViewCell is flickering after reloadSection

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have some problems with reloading section in tableView. If the cell is hiding a bit on the top, it becomes flicking. If the cell is fully visible, everything works fine. The height of cell is fixed, and it's not automaticDimension. All of cells are standard UITableViewCell with different background color. I know that tableView is a very common UI element in ios, and I hope someone had faced the same problem before. Thanks!

[image]

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return contactsForSections.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let contact = contactsForSections[section]
    return contact.isExpanded ? contact.numbers.count : 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        let cell = UITableViewCell()
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = .green
        return cell
    } else {
        let cell = UITableViewCell()
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = .red
        return cell
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 100
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

    guard indexPath.row == 0 else { return }

    contactsForSections[indexPath.section].isExpanded.toggle()

    tableView.reloadSections([indexPath.section], with: .none)
}
```

Comment: You should dequeue a reusable cell rather than creating a new `UITableViewCell` each time.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I tried it, but result is the same :(